# How to level concrete surface?

Tags: concrete, patio

I have a concrete patio thats been tiled over. Part of the patio is lower than the rest so it collects water. How do I level it off? I guess pull up the tiles and add another layer of cement to the lower part. Is there another way?

Comment: How much lower?  A picture of the problem and the surrounding area would likely tell us more than words can express.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Maybe a cm or 2. Not that big of difference. Just enough for a bit of water to collect.  Sorry about no picture. My picture is too big to upload. Haha something else I have to figure out.

Comment: the water pools over a portion of the tile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you mentioned is usually the correct way to go, as long as the settlement was not only developing recently. You might want to find some self-leveling concrete product. An example would be the Rapid Set CTS concrete leveler (in US).

Please do follow the manufacture's instructions, especially about properly preparing the old concrete surface so that the nearly poured concrete could bound well with your existing surface.

If your settlement started recently, it would be better to figure out the cause before repairing. For example, examine if there is any water leak that could washout your soil.

Comment: I would agree but if settling was the cause it may require hydraulic jacking. I have rented equipment to do this in the past. Basicly holes are drilled grout / sand and other mixes can be pumped under the slab so it drains away, but removing the tile resurfacing may be required if not due to settling.+

Comment: Yeah the concrete was orginally poured over a year ago. Thanks for the detailed info. I'm in South Korea, and their way of doing things is well... different. I'll see if I can find self leveling concrete over here. And figure out the instructions. Don't think this problem is big enough to require hydraulic pumping. Although might need that for the swimming pool. But thats a problem for another day and maybe a  different contractor hahah.